# How do I add 'required' to form label if specific option is set?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Using Rails, I would like to add: `<span class='req'>&bull;</span>` within my `<label>` tags in my views, if I set an option on the `label` form helper; i.e.

`<%= f.label :address_1, "Address 2:", :req => true -%>`

should produce:

`<label for="model_address_1"><span class='req'>&bull;</span> Address 1:</label>`

rather than:

`<label for="model_address_1" req="true">Address 1:</label>`

as it does now. I realise I may have to override the default form builder or create my own form builder, but don't know how to do this. Any suggestions? Thanks in advance!

**Update:** I'm doing this in an attempt to DRY up my code, and I realise that I could just paste the `span` snippet above into all the labels in all of my views but I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is untested, but something along these lines should work.

```
# in lib/labeled_form_builder.rb
class LabeledFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def label(field_name, label = nil, options = {})
    if options.delete(:req)
      label ||= field_name.to_s.humanize
      label = @template.content_tag(:span, "&bull;", :class => "req") + " " + label
    end
    super(field_name, label, options)
  end
end
```

And then use that builder in your view

```
<%= form_for @item, :builder => LabeledFormBuilder do |f| %>
```

You might be interested in Episode 3 of my [Mastering Rails Forms screencast series](http://www.pragprog.com/screencasts/v-rbforms/mastering-rails-forms) where I go into detail on creating form builders.

Comment: Works a treat Ryan, thanks very much! I'll check the screencast out :-)

Comment: This works great for Rails 2, but in Rails 3 the output is escaped, and comes out looking like 

    Detail <span class="req">*</span>

I tried putting the #raw method in different places, with no luck. Has anyone gotten something like this to work with Rails 3?

Answer (score 0):

Small change to ryanb's to get it to work in Rails 3. You just need to tell content_tag to not escape the bullet.

```
class LabeledFormBuilder < ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder
  def label(field_name, options = {}, label = nil)
    if options.delete(:req)
      label ||= field_name.to_s.humanize
      label = @template.content_tag(:span, "&bull;", {:class => "req"}, false) + " " + label
    end
    super(field_name, label, options)
  end
end
```